# Add element to typescript Record<>

Tags: typescript, set, record

I have a Record set up like this:
`let myRecord = Record<String, Set<String>>`

How can I add an element to a set inside the record? I have tried the following without success:

```js
let key = "key";
let stringToAdd = "stringToAdd";
myRecord[key].add(stringToAdd);
```

Comment: What does "without success" mean?

Answer (score 26):

You can use the square brackets `[]` and an assignment to add elements to the record.

```
let mySet: Set<string> = new Set();
mySet.add("stringToAdd");

let myRecord: Record<string, Set<string>> = {};

myRecord["key"] = mySet;    // <--- Like this
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. First you want to use the lowercase `string`. There is a difference (`String` is the new-able constructor), but just know that you want the lowercase version for any basic type.

Second you are mixing up types and values when you do `let myRecord = Record<String, Set<String>>`. You cannot set a variable to a type.  You can declare the type of the variable but you also need to set the value.

```
let myRecord: Record<string, Set<string>> = {};
```

This creates a variable `myRecord` whose initial value is an empty object `{}` and whose type is `Record<string, Set<string>>`.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/qNBvkN)

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add').